# Dart: access the caller instance from a function

Tags: function, dart

How could I access the "caller" instance from a function. The following code throws a syntax error:

```
// Error: Local variables cannot be referenced before they are declared
Function listener = (Event event) {
   print(listener);
};
```

I would like to access the "listener" variable from inside the function. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Function listener;
listener = (Event event) {
  print(listener);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Another way can be: listener(Event event) {print(listener);};